# How to sweeten ganache for a chocolate lining

Tags: pie, ganache

I'd like a chocolate lining in a banana cream pie, very similar to [this recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/banana-cream-pie-with-chocolate-lining/). However, I notice in the final pie that the chocolate lining is a little on the bitter side. What is a good way to sweeten it up? I'm no expert on ganache, but my understanding is I shouldn't just add sugar as it will turn grainy.  If I melt sugar into the cream before the chocolate, how much should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While adding sugar syrups like corn syrup or invert syrup to ganache is fairly common, it will change the texture of the ganache. You'd end up with something more like a chocolate coating.

If bitterness specifically is the problem, I'd suggest using a less bitter chocolate. Perhaps you can find something with lower cocoa solids that will have a smoother flavor without adding any sweeteners.

Added from a comment since I remembered: A tiny amount of salt can also help to cover bitterness. You could try that.

Comment: What do you think of melting sugar into the cream? Would that get grainy? OP, whatever sweetener you choose (if you do end up using a sweetener), how much to use is a matter of taste.

Comment: As long as it was totally dissolved, it shouldn't get grainy. I'd probably go with a superfine sugar just to be safe though. My main concern would be that dissolving the sugar would end up with some of the same effects as a syrup (hygroscopic stuff). And also, as has come up before on here, a pinch of salt can do a lot to eliminate bitterness.

Comment: Well, it looks like I have some experimenting to do. Lots of options. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Let us know what you find?